# GUI application to show employee record one at a time and stop at the end of the record

Tags: java, swing

I have this program that allows a user to click next or previous to view employee records.i have 4 empployees in the txt.The problem am having is when i click next or previous it keeps reading passed the last employee on record.What can i change to stop it?please advise.

Here the action listener part of the code.

```
    public Employee1(EmployeeDataSet employees) 
     {

        this.numberOfEmployees = employees.getEmployeeCount();
        this.employees = employees;
     } 

    public void loadEmployeeInGUI(Employee e)
    {
        // set text field with name
        Q1Field.setText(e.getName());
        // set text field with title
        Q2Field.setText(e.getName());
        // set textfield with salary
        Q3Field.setText(String.valueOf(e.getSalary()));
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x)
   {
        if (x.getSource() == Next)
   {
            index++;

            if(index == this.numberOfEmployees) index=0;
            Employee e = employees.getEmployeeAtIndex(index);
            loadEmployeeInGUI(e);
    }
    }
        if (x.getSource() == Previous) index--;
        if (index ==-1) index = this.numberOfEmployees -1;
    }
```

Comment: Your open/close braces are arranged in kind of a strange way. Did they get lost in translation when you wrote the question or is that how they look in the code? Specifically, why are there two open braces at the beginning of the actionPerformed method?

Answer (score 4):

This code appears to be using Java Swing. That being said, you should use [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). By associating an individual `Employee` with each "card", you'll be able to easily navigate (forward and backward) through the records.

This approach essentially delegates the "hard work" to the layout manager, which is how it should be.

Comment: so that means i have to change my Gui part to CardLayout.isnt there anything i can add or change so it just reads the specific number of employees?thanks for the CardLayout tip.

Comment: @Angel918: Not necessarily. You'd only need a different layout for distinct employee types. All your employees appear identical, so one layout should do.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree about the CardLayout. Using a CardLayout means you will create a `Component` for each `Employee`, which might be a significant number.
It is mentioned in the question that he currently only has 4 `Employee` instances for which you can still opt for a `CardLayout`, but it is not scalable at all.

Having a UI on which you can 'set' an Employee, and which will update its value accordingly (as it is already the case in the code provided in the start post) seems like the way to go.

Why his specific code does not result in the desired behavior is hard to tell since the open/close braces do not seem to match, and we have no idea how this `EmployeeDataSet` is implemented. But I prefer the used approach above a `CardLayout`

Comment: *"but it is not scalable at all."*  Given a typical GUI can easily hold 10s of thousands of cards, and your typical (HR) employee would only look at a couple of hundred per day, I cannot understand why you think it is 'not scalable at all'.

Comment: Since you have to make them. Opening the panel to show your employee-details would require to create a component for each employee, and add it to the cardlayout. What do you gain by doing that,certainly if only a couple of hundred will be looked at in a day

Comment: I agree that re-using one 'employeeDetails' component makes more sense, but I am contesting the statement 'not scalable at all'.  Your words, not mine.

Comment: I stand by my words. For example with a DB storing all the employee details you would have to query the DB for all employees, create components for all employees, add them all to the cardlayout, and then show the details of one employee. Of course you could paginate the DB-query, but what is the purpose of using a CardLayout in that case. So my 'non-scalable' is performance wise (both CPU and memory), not code-wise (which comes down to a simple for loop)

Comment: `CardLayout` would be required only if some employees needed a different layout: s/not scalable at all/not necessary in this context/. Here's an [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/googleolympiad) that uses a single layout to navigate among images. +1 for defending a simpler approach.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would restructure as follows:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x) {

    // handle increment / decrement
    if (x.getSource() == Next) {
        index++;
    }
    if (x.getSource() == Previous) {
        index--;
    }

    // range check
    if( index > this.numberOfEmployees ) {
        index = 0;
    }
    if( index < 0 ) {
        index = this.numberOfEmployees - 1;
    }

    // load up data
    Employee e = employees.getEmployeeAtIndex(index);
    loadEmployeeInGUI(e);
}
```